# Define $f:A \times \{b\} \to A$ as $ f(a,b) = a$. Prove it is bijective.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I get that I have to show that it is injective and surjective.  But I'm confused as to how to show that with an ordered pair to a single element.

Comment: Do you know some information about $A$ and $B$? This mapping is not bijective for arbitrary sets.

Comment: B should actually be {b} I realized I typed it in wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Injective:

Let $f(a,b)=f(c,b)$ then since $f(a,b)=a$ and $f(c,b)=c$ we have $a=c$ and hence $(a,b)=(c,b)$.

Surjective:

For any $a\in A$, we have $f(a,b)=a$ where $(a,b)\in A\times\{b\}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Injectivity:**

Let $f(a_1,b)=f(a_2,b)$ implying $a_1=a_2$, and hence $(a_1,b)=(a_2,b)$, hence $f$ is injective.

**Surjectivity:**

Take any $a\in A$ then look at $(a,b)\in A\times\{b\}$. Then note $f(a,b)=a$ which shows $f$ is surjective.